# Jquery code returned from Ajax call doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using Jquery UI sortable:

```
  $("ul.filter_age").sortable({
    handle: ".handle",
    update: function (event, ui) {

        var data = $('#formage').serialize();

        $.ajax({

            data:   data,
            type:   'POST',
            url:    '/path/to/php/script',
            success:function(data) {

                $('#age_form').html(data);

            }

        });

    }

  });
```

So once someone performs a sort, I then have it call a php script where it takes the information and updates the view order in the database. Then I am grabbing all the data from the database and outputting it back to the jquery script so they can see the updated view order. However when this happens, the sortable script no longer works. I cannot drag the list after ajax updates it.

So the question is, how do I make a call via jquery/ajax and have the returning html replace the existing html and have sortables still work? The returned html is identical to the original sortable html. Do I have to re-initialize the sortable jquery code inside the success function?

Answer (score 0):

Ok what I did was put it into a function and called it this way. Please let me know if this is the optimal way of doing this or if there is a better way... Thank you!

```
function updateAgeSort() {
$("ul.filter_age").sortable({
    handle: ".handle",
    update: function (event, ui) {

        var data = $('#formage').serialize();

        $.ajax({

            data:   data,
            type:   'POST',
            url:    '/path/to/php/script',
            success:function(data) {

                $('#age_form').html(data);

                updateAgeSort();

            }

        });

    }

  });
}

updateAgeSort();
```